# Elasticsearch or Solr + Mysql tables search

Tags: php, mysql, search, solr, elasticsearch

I'm a newbie to both Solr & Elasticsearch. I have a web application written in PHP with MYSQL as DB. I have 5 columns which contains text data. I want to index and apply search (from Elasticsearch/Solr) on these 5 columns only. I did google quite a bit and did not get it.

For example :

1. I have 5 columns viz. Title, Description, Review, Comments, Others.
2. The user visits http://www.my_site.com and enters his/her search query
3. Now I want my application to search all columns as mentioned in 1. and return the result.

(Mysql supports search across multiple columns, but its not complete and works like "SQL_LIKE". I want a search engine like the one's used in e-commerce sites)

Comment: show the code youve tried, and where you've gone wrong please

Comment: To let people be able to help, you should post what you have tried so far

Comment: This is how i got the basic thing up and running. Thanks @dadoonet. (0) Installed JDBC River plugin (1) Started the elasticsearch server  (2) Indexed the data using curl -GET 'localhocurl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{ ........ "index" : {
        "index" : "jdbc",
        "type" : "jdbc"
    }
}' (3) Wrote a simple JSON Parser in PHP:                         $input = "http://localhost:9200/jdbc/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*" . $_GET["q"] ."*" ;
 $JSON = file_get_contents($input);
 $values = json_decode($JSON, true); [HOPE I'M DOING RIGHT, PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'm WRONG]

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to index documents (aka rows from your example).
If your data are in MySQL, I suggest that you use :

- [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org)
- [Elasticsearch JDBC River](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

Launch Elasticsearch, Add the river, and start to search.

You can have a look at [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) for a PHP Client.

Comment: This is how i got the basic thing up and running. Thanks @dadoonet. (0) Installed JDBC River plugin (1) Started the elasticsearch server  (2) Indexed the data using curl -GET 'localhocurl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{ ........ "index" : {
        "index" : "jdbc",
        "type" : "jdbc"
    }
}' (3) Wrote a simple JSON Parser in PHP:                         $input = "http://localhost:9200/jdbc/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*" . $_GET["q"] ."*" ;
 $JSON = file_get_contents($input);
 $values = json_decode($JSON, true); [HOPE I'M DOING RIGHT, PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'm WRONG]

Comment: I would say please do not provide some links to make further RnD unless you have concrete example to share or the information is really meaningful.  Googling a link/information is easy.

Comment: Elasticsearch JDBC River is deprecated now .. itz no longer working